# how to assemble data in an array by a value in php

Tags: php

i have an array like this :

```
[
    ['external_account' => 'AAA', 'label' => 'Nbr de client', 'value' => 1],
    ['external_account' => 'AAA', 'label' => 'TTC', 'value' => 1],
    ['external_account' => 'BBB', 'label' => 'HT', 'value' => 0],
]
```

and i want to assemble data by external_account value and have an outpout (array) like this one

```
[
    [
        'external_account' => 'AAA',
        'data' => [
            ['label' => 'Nbr de client', 'value' => 1],
            ['label' => 'TTC', 'value' => 1]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'external_account' => 'BBB',
        'data' => [
            ['label' => 'HT', 'value' => 0]
        ]
    ]
]
```

my code so far :

```
foreach ($result as $current_key => $current_array) {
    $assemble = [];
    foreach ($result as $search_key => $search_array) {
        if (
            $current_key != $search_key &&
            $current_array["external_account"] ==
                $search_array["external_account"]
        ) {
            $valeur = $current_array["external_account"];

            array_push(
                $assemble,
                $current_array["label"],
                $current_array["value"]
            );
            unset($result[$current_key]);
        }
        $data[] = ["external_account" => $valeur, "data" => $assemble];
    }
}
```

please tell me what am doing wrong, am stuck on it.

The output of my code : [enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/2NBEzaq7)

Comment: What is the result from the posted code? It makes it much easier for us to find potential issues if we know what problem we're trying to solve.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i added the output am getting from my code

Comment: Please copy/paste it into the question instead of in a link to a pastebin or the question won't be clear for future visitors when that link expires.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i can't poste too much code in my question, it says too much code, plus pastebin links doesn't expires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks more complicated than it needs to be. For grouping problems like this, it's just a matter of using the thing you want to group by as a key as you build your result.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $item) {
    // extract the first key (external_account)
    $account = array_shift($item);

    // then use it as the key to group your data
    $result[$account]['external_account'] = $account;
    $result[$account]['data'][] = $item;
}
```

If you don't want to keep that key in your result, you can remove it with

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: yeah it sounded easy for me at first place but after struggling with it for half a day i did give up to be honnest, but your answer saved me, thanks for your time